# Is there any way to call a c/c++ file from a trigger in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I want to call a c++/bash-script file through a trigger in postgresql. Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: C++ and bash scripts are two **very** different things. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: pl/perlu and pl/python can kick off an external script

Comment: I want to call a bash script from a postgresql, because if we can call a bash script, then via bash script we can call a c++ file.

Comment: that's probably a really bad idea,

Answer (score -1):

## Yes, you can write a trigger function in C.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xfunc-c.html

Comment: so, it's a link only answer, that page is likely to be visible for at-least the next 10 years. those guys never delete documentation.